# Replace Multiple apk with single apk Google Play Console

Tags: android, multiple-apk

I have published my app using multiple apk's concept (armeabi, armeabi-v7, x86)  Now i'm trying to publish update version of app but using ONE apk instead multiple.

Do users with armeabi, armeabi-v7, x86 apk's get their updates?

Comment: http://developer.sonymobile.com/2011/10/11/use-the-multiple-apk-support-in-android-market/

Comment: Oscar LT, thanks for replying, but it is all about how to upload multiple apk, but I need to upload single apk instead multiple.

Answer (score 0):

You can publish a One Apk instead of multiple-apk. The rule you have to follow is to make sure the new APK get a build number greater than any build before, to make sure user get the update.